# Crash/hang when external monitor is connected during login

Tags: login, crash, multiple-monitors

When I log into my Dell M3800 with the external display connected (via DP), Ubuntu freezes: Shows only the background image, mouse pointer still works, but no keys etc.

If I log in with the 2nd display disconnected, and connect it after the login, everything works fine.

This only happens for my user - if I log in with the guest account and 2nd display connected, there's no prob.

Also, the login screen is shown perfectly on both displays, the crash happens right after the login.

The problem appears since the upgrade to 16.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the manufacturer of your graphic card?

Comment: @Michal - I only use the integrated Intel HD 4600 (it also has a Nvidia Quadro K1100M)